# Composite surrogate foreign keys as PK or a separate surrogate key

Tags: database-design

The picture below shows two alternative database designs.  One with a composite of two foreign keys and one with its own surrogate key.  The second option will have a composite unique constraint on DanceGroupId and StudioId so two of the same can't be entered.  I have always employed the first design but after architecting my classes in C# it would aid C# code reuse if I could put a common non-composite surrogate key on all my tables.  In terms of database design, what are the negatives of using a surrogate on a table like Booking instead of a composite?

[image]

I'm not looking for a general composite vs surrogate debate here, its slightly different because my composite key in option one is composed of foreign keys.  As far as I'm aware surrogates are favoured over natural keys due to their non-reliance on business related data.  This is not a concern in this scenario and never has been however I've never seen this approach before on a 'middle' table.  It seems reasonable to implement it like in the second option but I was wondering if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible negatives of defining a pseudokey when you don't need to:

- One extra superfluous integer per row makes rows wider, uses more space on disk and in memory.
- More contention on the mechanism is used to generate the unnecessary pseudokey values.
- Spoiling the use of the clustered index for extra performance. It makes sense to define the clustering index to match the most common queries. For example, if your queries most often include conditions on StudioId, then make that the first column of the clustered index. In some SQL implementations (e.g. MySQL), the primary key is always used as the clustered index. In some other SQL implementations, you may choose another secondary unique key as the clustered index.

Comment: Thanks Bill that seems like a good response :-)  I guess its a case of weighing up the memory and performance requirements of the system and code reuse.  These considerations may well be minimal for the solutions I have in mind for my app.